Oracle PL/SQL FOR loops with multiple iteration controls cause a syntax error
I'm studying PL/SQL and trying to run some samples of multiple iteration controls in FOR loops. I'm taking these samples directly from Oracle PL/SQL docs - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-C4BC9960-5945-4646-BBDE-DC00346F8702 so I'm confident that they should be syntactically correct, however every single sample code with more than 1 iteration control causes the same syntax error.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I've exhausted my ideas and this is driving me nuts..
All of these:
DECLARE
   i PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..3, REVERSE i+1..i+10, 51..55 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
   END LOOP;
END;

BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..3, 6..8
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
   END LOOP;
END;

BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1, REPEAT i*2 WHILE i < 100 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
   END LOOP;
END;

produce the same error:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

* & - + / at loop mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> ||
multiset
Error at Line: 11 Column: 0

The error is always pointing to the position of the comma, however removing the comma obviously doesn't solve the issue.

It turns out I'm running Oracle 19c database and these code samples only work with Oracle 21c version. Question solved.
